# Win7 - Batch convert script - mp3 to ogg?

Tags: audio, batch, vlc-media-player, conversion, mp3

Trying to convert some mp3 to ogg using VLC on Win7.

I started by modifying what I found here, but couldn't get it to work:
[How to convert several files of one type (e.g. wav to mp3) using VLC or Audacity at a single blow?](https://superuser.com/questions/617011/how-to-convert-several-files-of-one-type-e-g-wav-to-mp3-using-vlc-or-audacity)

So the script I have currently:

```
@echo off
for /f "delims=|" %%f in (dir /b "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC_batch\*.mp3") do (
echo %%f
CALL "C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe" "%%f" --sout=#transcode{acodec=vorb,ab=192,vcodec=dummy}:standard{access=file,mux=raw,dst=converted/%%f}  vlc://quit
move "%%f" trash/"%%f"
)

cd converted
ren *.mp3 *.ogg
cd ..
pause
```

The error is:

```
The system cannot find the file dir
The system cannot find the file specified
```

I put the music files to convert in the C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\VLC_batch directory, and I have "trash" and "converted" both in the batch directory and in the VLC directory.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put a single quote around your command...

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in (dir /b...
```

becomes

```
for /f "delims=|" %%f in ('dir /b...
```

Though with the double-quote you use later to call VLC, I'm betting you need to start out with double quotes and include the C:\Program... part in single quotes.  Give that a try.

Comment: Agreed. The first error is because the `dir` command was not encapsulated. The second error is because the rename operation failed since there is no converted file