# Transcode Multiple Video Files at a Time in VLC

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, video-conversion, transcode

I am using VLC to transcode video files, in the convert/save menu it lets you select multiple files, but when you click Convert, it just converts the first file in the list. Ideally I would be able to open as many files as I want, and then select a folder for it to output the converted files to. Is there a way to do this that I am missing?

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1229286/327942), it works for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to do batch transcoding, you will need to download version 3.0.0 of VLC from [nightlies.videolan.org](http://nightlies.videolan.org)

Then open multiple files in the Convert/Save menu, then click convert, select the format, and click Start.

Comment: I've tried this, but nothing happens after I click Start. I see the list of files and it says "Converting X" next to each of them. When I convert a single file, the file is immediately converted.